# How to seat 32 people at two tables that can seat 16 people each, out of a pool of 380 people?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, word-problem

A random combinatorics question some old guy asked me, I haven't done much combinatorics in my life at all, my initial answer was $\frac{380!}{32!358!}*\frac{32!}{16!16!}$

I have three exams this week, just curious about how to do a question like this.. If anyone can explain, much appreciated!

Comment: Not complete. How many ways are there to seat 16 people in a table? (usually table is a round?) or what's different between seating around a table or standing in a queue for 16 people?

Comment: There are many missing bits of information here.  First, are the tables different?  Like... is there a table with blue chairs and a table with red chairs and the color of the chairs that the people sit at matter?  (*I.e. if we took an arrangement of people and swapped which table everyone was sitting at keeping everything the same apart from which table is which, are these considered different arrangements?*)  Does arrangement around the table matter?  (*If we were to shift everyone one seat to the right, is it still considered the same?*)

Comment: they can be seated in any way at each table

Comment: That does not answer any of my questions nor does it answer any of Ehsan's questions.

Comment: To make it clearer, if the tables have four seats and people are labeled by numbers, is the arrangement $\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\4&3\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}5&6\\8&7\end{bmatrix}$ considered the same or different than either of the arrangements $\begin{bmatrix}5&6\\8&7\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$ (*having swapped which table was which*) or $\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\2&1\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}5&6\\8&7\end{bmatrix}$ (*having rotated people around one of the tables, but keeping who is sitting by who the same, e.g. to the right of $1$ is always $4$ and to the left is $2$*)

Comment: Ok, so swapping tables counts as different. But people sitting in different chairs, doesn't matter.

Comment: "*But people sitting in different chairs, doesn't matter*", so the table $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$ is considered the same table to you as $\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\4&2\end{bmatrix}$?  This is despite the fact that $1$ is not sitting next to $3$ in the first seating but is sitting next to $3$ in the second seating?

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Comment: With those assumptions, your answer is correct.  This is not how I would have interpreted the problem however, and is not how most people would interpret the problem I expect.  The more common interpretation is for changing which table was which would keep arrangements the same and for rotations only of people at the table (*but not other rearrangements of people*) to be considered the same.  The answer to that interpretation would be $\binom{380}{32}\binom{31}{15}(15!)^2$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I apologize for the late reply (busy with exams). I asked the guy who gave me the problem to clear up the questions you raised above and I came away with the interpretation I gave you. I see why your answer works, thank you Sir.